# How to re-install updates to Google system apps?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean, system-apps, google-play-services

I have Android 4.2.2 on my phone. A few weeks ago Google Play was acting weird and would not install updates to some of the apps. I tried lots of things but nothings worked. Eventually I uninstalled the updates of Google Play Store (back to 3.10.10) and Google Play Services (to 1.0.15), thinking even if it didn't help I could reinstall the updates later. I was asked "Do you want to uninstall all updates to this android system app?" each time and I continued. Turned out it actually worked and I could install those apps that I could not install before. I decided to leave them as old versions since they seemed to work better.

Fast forward a few weeks, now there are some apps that give me errors when Google Play tries to update them. So I want to update Google Play Store and Google Play Services back to the original (and newer) version but I can't figure out how. Any suggestions as to how I can do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your phone isn't rooted. If you know exactly what build/version you're after then do a quick Google search for 'Google Play Services XXX.apk' and manually install the later version over the top of your current one, and the same for the next one. They are available on aptoide, blackmart and other alternate stores.

If you get any packages error, or system error, I would suggest just do a reformat and reinstall all your content- it's generally quicker than scowering the net for the cause behind the issue.

Comment: Thanks. Mine is rooted, but how do I figure which version I should get?

Comment: @ceilingcat In this instance, determine your current version and search the listing available. I'm sure a simple search for Google Play Services will give you a list and change log. If you're having difficulty knowing what version you're on, just use an app extractor and extract your version.